# How to make GridBagLayout more logical

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I have the following code below:

```
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    config.add(first = new JTextArea(), c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    config.add(second = new JTextArea(), c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 10;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;

    config.add(bottom, c);
```

And currently I get the following Screenshot:
[image]

"bottom" is by button panel. For starters, the two text fields are merged together, and the buttons should be on the bottom. Looking at the Oracle instructions on GridBagLayout didn't help too much. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably should use the `BorderLayout` instead.

Comment: My suggestion to you is to abandon all the layouts and use [Mig layout](http://www.miglayout.com/) for all of your layout problems. Layouts provided by oracle are very buggy at best, and hard to use efficiently unless you have a really good experience with them.

Comment: @Quillion Which specific layouts from Oracle are buggy, and specifically in what way?  I haven't found that to be the case at all for any standard LayoutManager.

Comment: For better help sooner, please post a [Minimal Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem. Many times, just creating the example will reveal the problem.

Comment: @splungebob I found most of them to be guilty of max size/min size. And overall to do simplest tasks is difficult because one feature can override another feature. Non Oracle layouts written by users are so much more pleasant to use and understand. Maybe the learning curve for Oracle layouts is too high, so I never bothered diving in depth and remain Oracle layout noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that your class extends from JPanel then calling
 super(new GridBagLayout())
at the first line of your constructor may solve the issue...

Try adding this line as well
 c.width=GridBagConstaints.REMAINDER;